# Python Basics How do I work out the year of birth from a persons age?

Tags: python-3.x

Total beginner at Python 3 and was wondering how do I calculate the year of birth from persons age?

So far I have:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
age = input("Hello {0}, How old are you?".format(name))
print("Hello {0}, your age is {1}".format(name, age))
#getting the year
import datetime
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
print("your year of birth is {2}".format( year - age )) #stuck here
```

Thanks

Comment: since you are not considering the month and day of birth, depending on what month and day we are NOW the result of your code can be ONE year off so a more accurate method is to ask the date birth month and date for accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to look at. First are the types of the operand `year` and `age`. `year` is an integer while `age` is a string, and the `-` operator expected that both operands be integers, so `age` needs to be `int(age)`. Second, the index for the formatted string is off; it needs to be at the zeroth index since there's only one value.

```
print("your year of birth is {0}".format(year - int(age)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you age input needs to be an int, since an int can't operate with a string:

```
import datetime

name = input('What is your name? ')
age = int(input('Hello {0}, How old are you? '.format(name)))
print('Hello,',name,'your age is',age)

year = (datetime.datetime.today().year)-age

print('Your year of birth is',year)
```

output:

```
What is your name? bob
Hello bob, How old are you? 6
Hello, bob your age is 6
Your year of birth is 2012
```